# what is use of this::instanceMethod use as method parameter in java8

Tags: java

I just started learning java8 stream api. I have seen a method which has input type `Runnable` interface even it's allow to pass `this::greet` as param. when program is run, why does this not call greet method? its output only `Hello, world!2`. why does it allow to pass such method even input is runnable interface?

```
public class TestAnno {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestAnno anno=new TestAnno();
    }
    public TestAnno() {
        display(this::greet); // what is use of calling this method
        display(this.greet()); //compiler error: The method display(Runnable) in the type TestAnno is not applicable for the arguments (void)
    }
    private  void display(Runnable s) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!2");
        //Arrays.sort(new String[]{"1","2"}, String::compareToIgnoreCase);

    }
    public void greet() {
        System.out.println("Hello, world! greet");

    }
}
```

I have created interface to understand it.

```
public interface Inter1 {
 void hello();
 void hello1(int a);
}
```

Now I change display method param to `Inter1` instead of `Runnable`. it throw error 'The target type of this expression must be a functional interface'.

like

```
public class TestAnno {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestAnno anno=new TestAnno();
    }
    public TestAnno() {
        display(this::greet); // The method display(Inter1) in the type TestAnno is not applicable for the arguments (this::greet)
        display(()->this.greet());//The target type of this expression must be a functional interface

    }
    /*private  void display(Runnable s) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!2");
        Arrays.sort(new String[]{"1","2"}, String::compareToIgnoreCase);

    }*/
    private  void display(Inter1 s){

    }
    public void greet() {
        System.out.println("Hello, world! greet");

    }


}
```

Can any one help on this!!

Comment: What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: I don't understand why it's not showing error. If I want to use such concept again for any class design, what things are required in my interface i.e.`Runnable`, any other custom interface. or a method param should have?

Comment: You can pass in place of a `Runnable` any method that takes no arguments and returns `void`.

Comment: @sdgfsdh updated question. create a seperate interface which has two method. even it does not call empty one. and throw compilation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this::greet` refers to a method with no parameters and no return value. As such, it matches the single method of the `Runnable` interface - `void run()`.

Your display method accepts a `Runnable` instance. It must execute that's `Runnable`'s `run` method in order for your `greet` method to be executed :

```
private  void display(Runnable s) {
    s.run();
    System.out.println("Hello, world!2");
}
```

Your second attempt to call `display` can pass compilation if you turn it into a lambda expression :

```
display(()->this.greet());
```

Comment: thanks. I understood. :) If I have two method with no paramter, it throws error. is there any way to deal with?

Comment: @bmt What do you mean by that? What two methods? Please be more specific.

Comment: @bmt A functional interface can only have a single abstract method. `Inter1` doesn't work, since it contains two methods.

Comment: thanks for your input. its really helps.!!